# Protractor fails going to angular latest section of our app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript, protractor

We are upgrading our application from AngularJS to the Angular latest.

I am trying to create some tests which start out in the AngularJS version of the app and navigate to admin application which is in the Angular latest version of the app. Below is the test I am trying to run.

```js
describe('Admin App - Create Users', () => {
      beforeAll(async() => {
        await loginPage.login(companyUser, companyUserPwd)
        await common.navigationOpenByClick()
        await navPage.navigateToApp(AppParams.apps.admin.navLink)
        await admin.navigateAdmin('Users')
      })

      afterAll(async() => {
        await common.signOut()
      })

      _.forEach(CommonStrings.Strings.differentStrings, firstName => {
        it(`Create a New User First Name - ${firstName}`, async() => {
          await admin.createNewUser({
            userConfig: {
              firstName
            },
            clickSave: false
          })
          expect(admin.newUserAcceptBtn.getAttribute('disabled')).toBe(`true`)
          await admin.newUserCancelBtn.click()
        })
      })
}
```

In the `beforeEach()` I navigate to the admin application and then click the `Users` link to go to that section within the admin application. The problem is that it is never clicking the `Users` section and instead throws the following error:

`Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details"`

So I clicked the link in that and they discussed that the cause of this is due to a redirect which is the case. So I tried the following after the `await navPage.navigateToApp()` line in the `beforeEach()`. I also tried several of the suggestions within that ticket mentioned in the error and none helped.

`browser.sleep()` this helped, sort of, the error above went away, but I ran into the `allScriptsTimeout` in my protractor.config file.

`browser.refresh()` no help

`browser.wait(EC.urlContains('end of link to the admin application'))` This helped in that the error went away, but I run into the `allScriptsTimeout`

Just wondering what else I can try to get this test suite to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by doing two things in my `beforeEach()`
First, after logging into the application I navigate directly to the section of the program I want, by doing an `await browser.get('/areaoftheapplication')`
Then right after that, I do an `await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)` and it works.

```
    beforeAll(async () => {
        await loginPage.login(companyUser, companyUserPwd)
        await browser.get('v2/admin')
        await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)
    })
```